# How to get list elements by matching string using scala?

Tags: list, scala

I have following list-

```
List((name1,233,33),(name2,333,22),(name3,444,55),())
```

I have another string which I want to match with list and get matched elements from list.
There will be only one element in list that matches to given string.

The list may contains some empty elements as given as last element in above list.

Suppose I am maching string 'name2' which will occurs only once in the list, then 
My expected output is -

```
List(name2,333,22)
```

How do I find matching list element using scala??

Comment: `.filter(_._1 == name2)`?

Comment: Should the output be `List(name2,333,22)` or really `List((name2,333,22))` ?

Comment: It should be List(name2,333,22)

Comment: Although this problem is solveable, it can be much easier and cleaner if you don't mix types in a List. May be there is another way to construct this List so that it is of type: List[(String, Int, Int)], not List[Any].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider `collect` over the tuples list, for instance like this,

```
val a = List(("name1",233,33),("name2",333,22),("name3",444,55),())
```

Then

```
a collect {
  case v @ ("name2",_,_) => v
}
```

If you want only the first occurrence, use `collectFirst`. This partial function ignores tuples that do not include 3 items.

Answer (score 6):

```
.find(_._1 == name2)
```

will be better